# Split one column in two in Excel (one column has all rows from both columns)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've queried some data and the output is copied as one column, so 1 single column like:

```
Column1
Column2
DataColumn1_value1
DataColumn2_value1
DataColumn1_value2
DataColumn2_value2
DataColumn1_value3
DataColumn2_value3
```

So that's the format I'm getting in Excel, I don't have any delimiter. What would be the best way to convert that into columns so it looks like a proper table

```
Column 1               Column 2
DataColumn1_Value 1    DataColumn2_Value 1
DataColumn1_Value 2    DataColumn2_Value 2
DataColumn1_Value 3    DataColumn2_Value 3
```

Comment: Sorting or index with match.

Comment: (a) How confident are you that it always follows this every-other-row pattern, which makes it super-easy.  (b) which version of excel, do you have O365?  And (c) is this just a one-time thing, or is this something you need to be able to sort of automate for ongoing use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data starts from cell A1:

Put this in column B, starting at cell B1 and drag down:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CEILING(2*ROW()-1), 1))
```

Put this in column C, starting at cell C1 and drag down:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CEILING(2*ROW()), 1))
```

Result:

[image]

After that, if you needed to move the data around you could copy as value and go from there!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Column 1

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROW()*2-1)
```

Column 2

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROW()*2)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=WRAPROWS(A1:A8,2)
```